# Adding additional Metadata field in AEM-DAM

Tags: adobe, aem, dam

I want to add a custom metadata field in DAM assets, is there any way to add custom metadata apart from overlaying a workflow or writing custom workflow?

Comment: See if this helps https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/metadata_for_digitalassetmanagement.html (Search for Creating New Metadata Property for Assets)

Comment: Asset editor and Viewer won't do the job for me. I am looking at a way to add metadata on upload of asset in DAM

Answer (score 0):

Metadata profiles is the way to add default properties to assets on upload. Metadata profiles are linked to assets at folder level. You could have different default properties for assets based on folder they are uploaded to. For e.g. attached default tags based on folder

Checkout this link for the detailed documentation on how to add metadata profile to a DAM folder
[Metadata Profiles](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/assets/using/metadata-profiles.html)