# How to add custom metadata field in Asset programatically during the creation of asset

Tags: adobe, aem, livefyre

I want to add the custom metadata field in asset during asset creation. I have the referred the documentation for the asset class and asset manager class. I have used the createAsset function to create the asset.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dam="http://www.day.com/dam/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:mix="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:mixinTypes="[mix:referenceable]"
    jcr:primaryType="dam:Asset"
    jcr:uuid="11111111111111111111111">
    <jcr:content
        dam:relativePath="demo/demo"
        jcr:lastModified="{Date}2016-10-12T21:13:27.224+05:30"
        jcr:lastModifiedBy="dam-replication-service"
        jcr:primaryType="dam:AssetContent">
        <metadata
            dam:extracted="{Date}2016-10-12T21:13:27.164+05:30"
            dam:sha1="17cb9a4ba368ff01951a11c3ca7e3f8348eee59c"
            dam:size="{Long}1184"
            dc:format="application/demo"
            jcr:mixinTypes="[cq:Taggable]"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
        <related jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

This is a demo code. I want add an additional property in metadata say: **source="xyz"**. I have also referred this link [Adding additional Metadata field in AEM-DAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834622/adding-additional-metadata-field-in-aem-dam). 
Can some one please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly clear what issue you have in adding additional metadata field. There are couple of ways to do this -

1. Overlay the metadata form and add additional field as explained [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/content/assets/metadata/meta-edit.html)
2. If the source is automatically identifiable you could add a custom process (write your own process step and then add to model) step to update asset workflow - `/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html` or write an event listener (process intensive as it will get called multiple times when asset is imported and processed via workflows) which listens to Asset changes and adds the metadata field

Comment: I want to add add the custom mimetype property in the asset. Suppose I have function

Asset myAsset = assetManager.createAsset(path, byteArrayStream, "application/demo", true);

Comment: I want add the custom mimetype property after asset is created like source="xyz"

<metadata
            dam:extracted="{Date}2016-10-12T21:13:27.164+05:30"
            dam:sha1="17cb9a4ba368ff01951a11c3ca7e3f8348eee59c"
            dam:size="{Long}1184"
            dc:format="application/demo"
            jcr:mixinTypes="[cq:Taggable]"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>

Comment: Sorry for different comments. By mistake I have press enter and the comment is posted I don't see option to edit it.

Result would be:

<metadata
            dam:extracted="{Date}2016-10-12T21:13:27.164+05:30"
            dam:sha1="17cb9a4ba368ff01951a11c3ca7e3f8348eee59c"
            dam:size="{Long}1184"
            dc:format="application/demo"
            jcr:mixinTypes="[cq:Taggable]"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            source="xyz"/>

Comment: Refer here http://www.albinsblog.com/2015/07/Programatically-Set-Get-metadata-Asset-Adobe-CQ5-Adobe-AEM.html?m=1#.WAC1COyXenM

Comment: You could try asset.adapTo(Resource.class) and then follow the update steps in above link

Answer (score 1):

Use java Sling You can add like this i hope so:-

```
    session = resource.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
    Node node = session.getNode(resource.getPath());
    node.setProperty("hpe-un:objec_name", "my text");
```